# Javascript to check both checkbox not checked for one row

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox, displaytag

I am having two Checkbox for every row in a table with multiple rows. Here, i need to validate 
that user has selected checkbox for all the rows and also has not selected for both `approveCheck` and `rejectCheck`. The two hidden  Here is the sample code in jsp

```
<display:table>
<display:column title="Approve" >                                                               
<center>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='approveCheck'>
<input type="checkbox" name="approveCheck" value="${approve.num}" />
</center>                                                                                           
</display:column>
<display:column title="Reject" >                                                                
<center>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='rejectCheck'>
<input type="checkbox" name="rejectCheck" value="${approve.num}" />
</center>                                                                                           
</display:column>
</display table>
```

On Submit the javascript i am calling is:

```
function formCheck2(){

    var alertMsg = '';
    var checkedList1 = window.document.getElementsByName('approveCheck');
    var checkedList2 = window.document.getElementsByName('rejectCheck');
    var validationFlag = true;
    if(checkedList1 == '')checkedList1=0;
if(checkedList2 == '')checkedList2=0;

     mainloop:
    for(var i = 0; i < checkedList1.length; i++){
        for(var i = 0; i < checkedList2.length; i++){
            if(checkedList1 !='' && checkedList2 !=''){
             if ((checkedList1[i].checked == true || checkedList1[i].checked == "true") && (checkedList2[i].checked == true || checkedList2[i].checked == "true")){                 
                validationFlag = false;
                alertMsg = "Cannot check both";
                alert('both checked');
                break mainloop;
                }            
            else if ((checkedList1[i].checked == false || checkedList1[i].checked == "false") && (checkedList2[i].checked == false || checkedList2[i].checked == "false")){         
                validationFlag = false;
                alertMsg = "need to act on all";
                alert('none checked');
                break mainloop;
                }       
            else{           
                validationFlag = true;

             }
        }
        }
    }                   
    if(validationFlag){             
            window.document.forms["Rep"].btnSubmit.disabled = true;     
            window.document.forms["Rep"].action = '${urlSubmit}';       
            window.document.forms["Rep"].submit();              
    }
    else{
        alert(alertMsg);
        return false;   
    }
}
```

here no matter whatever i am selecting i selecting into the "need to act on all" block.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using radio buttons instead of check boxes, and group each two radio buttons using their name:

```
<input type="radio" name="Check1" value="${vdapprove.ddr_num}" onClick="toggle(this);"/>
<input type="radio" name="Check1" value="${vdapprove.ddr_num}" onClick="toggle(this);" />
```

This way you'll be sure that both can't be checked in the same time

**Note:
you may give them different IDs to be able to access each one of them based on their ID**

Comment: cannot give radio button as the requirement is giving checkboxes

Comment: Ok, another suggestion is to validate onClick, so in each checkbox, onClick would check if the other checkbox is checked, and if so alert, or uncheck the other checkbox.
onClick="Validate();"

<input type="checkbox" name="approveCheck" value="${vdapprove.ddr_num}" />
`<input type="checkbox" name="rejectCheck" value="${vdapprove.ddr_num}" />
function Validate(){
 var checkedList1 = window.document.getElementsByName('approveCheck');
    var checkedList2 = window.document.getElementsByName('rejectCheck');
 if(checkedList1[i].checked == true || checkedList1[i].checked == true)
  //Do something.
}`